# In Tkinter how to pass a called function as argument?

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter for constructing the menubar with the `<menu_item>.add_command()` we need a string for the `accelerator` argument which will create the hotkey binding for a command.

I created a method, which is checking if the user's platform is Mac or other, and if it is, then returns the `Command` key string combined with the other keys.

But it doesn't work -> the menu is building, if I click on the menu-item it is working, but not working with the hot-keys. ALthough I can see the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> in the menu..

My first thought is, that the `self.hot_key()` method is not called while passed as an argument..

```
import sys
import Tkinter

class app(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.gui.minsize(width=640, height=320)
        menu = Tkinter.Menu(self.gui)
        filemenu = Tkinter.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(
            label       = 'New',
            command     = self.New,
            accelerator = self.hot_key('n')
        )
        menu.add_cascade(
            label = 'File',
            menu  = filemenu
        )
        self.gui.config(menu=menu)

        self.text = Tkinter.Text(self.gui)
        self.text.pack(expand=Tkinter.YES, fill=Tkinter.BOTH)

    def hot_key(self, *keys):
        super_key = 'Command' if sys.platform == 'darwin' else 'Control'
        return '{super}+{keys}'.format(super=super_key, keys='+'.join(keys))

    def New(self):
        print "I'm working!"

App = app()
App.gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, I've never used this accelerator thing.  I always just `self.gui.bind_all(...)`, but that's probably a bit more ugly and hacky.

Comment: As it turns out, I have to use `bind` or `bind_all` to bind the keyboard event to a method, `accelerator` only displays the hot keys in a menu.. So your version is not ugly or hacky, that is the right way to do..

Comment: Good to know.  I learned something this morning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html) page,

> The "accelerator" option is used to indicate the menu accelerator that
>   should be associated with this menu. This does not actually create the
>   accelerator, but only displays what it is next to the menu item. You
>   still need to create a binding for the accelerator yourself.

So your `accelerator` keyword argument is working as designed -- the Command-N symbol appears in your menu.

As mgilson suggests in a comment, you can use `bind_all` to get the keyboard combination to actually do something.

```
self.gui.bind_all("<Command-n>", lambda event: self.New())
```

Comment: OK, there is only one thing now, I don't understand: if I use `bind` or `bind_all`, then the menu don't show me the shortcuts `⌘ + N`, even if they are defined in the `accelerator` -> why is that?

Comment: That's unusual. It works on my machine, using Windows 7 (and with "Control" in place of ⌘). Maybe it's an OS-specific problem?

Comment: Probably.. but for me this whole thing is soooo messy. I mean, why is there `command` and `accelerator` arguments in `add_command` if that can't bind to the keys.. it is confusing, not to mention it doesn't show correctly on OS X menu:(

Comment: @PeterVaro: the reason the accelerator doesn't do the binding for you is that there are multiple ways to do the binding, and tkinter doesn't know what your intent is. So, you can choose to display whatever you want as an accelerator, and you can choose to do the binding however you want. There's not always a direct 1:1 mapping of an accelerator key to a binding, and there's also not always a direct 1:1 mapping between a visible character in an accelerator and the actual key or keys that you bind to.

Comment: @PeterVaro: you say if you use bind that the accelerator doesn't show up. That seems highly unusual. Perhaps you can create a very small program that reproduces the problem, and then post a separate question about it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I solved the problem! If I use `key1+key2` in `accelerator` it won't show up with the binding (but shows up alone) but if I use `key1-key2` it is working fine alone and with binding as well.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "show up with the binding", but certainly, `key1+key2` is an invalid event specification so a binding to that definitely won't work. In other words, the syntax for a binding and the syntax for the accelerator is different.