# passing tkinter variable with get method called as argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have read the answer to this question:

[In Tkinter how to pass a called function as argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234943/in-tkinter-how-to-pass-a-called-function-as-argument)

and while it seems related it does not appear to answer my question as the issue in the above question is with the user defined function being called. I am passing a called method (the .get() method of a tkinter StringVar) to the built in 'print' function.
My code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

def print_called(variable):
    print(variable.get())

try:
    root = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.StringVar()
    options = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, 'string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3', 'string 4')
    button_1 = tk.Button(root, text='button_1', command=partial(print_called, var))
    button_2 = tk.Button(root, text='Button_2', command=partial(print, var.get()))

    options.pack()
    button_1.pack()
    button_2.pack()
finally:
    root.mainloop()
```

I run the above code and select 'string 1' from the menu. When I click button_1 it prints 'string 1' as expected. When I click button_2 it prints a blank line. My Questions are:

1. Why does this happen? Why is there a difference between the two?
2. How can I pass the result of var.get() (i.e. the string 'string 1') as an argument to a function?

Comment: I think `lambda` would do a better job, `command=lambda:print(var.get())`. It has to do with code flow and the fact that the value of `var` is `''` during its declaration

Comment: For `button_2`, you called `var.get()` as part of the creation of the Button - the value was blank, because nothing had yet had any chance to change the `StringVar` from its default value.  The value stored in the `partial` object isn't going to magically change just because the expression that originally generated it no longer has the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command=partial(print, var.get())` is evaluated directly when `button_2` is created. At this point nothing is selected, and `var.get()` returns an empty string.

You could use a lambda function: `command=lambda: print(var.get())`, but this is almost the same as what you did in `button_1`, just with a lambda function instead of a normal one.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the difference between partial and lambda? i.e. why is var.get() not evaluated at the time I create button 2 if I use lambda, but it is if I use partial? I'm fairly new to stackoverflow. Should I be posting this as a separate question?

Comment: In the case of the partial, `var.get()` is a parameter, in the other case it is in the body of the newly created (lambda-)function.